# (Python/Appium) When no element is found when searching by Accessibility ID NoSuchElementExeption is not hit

Tags: python, mobile, pytest, appium, ui-automation

When upgrading the version of appium we are using from `2.0.0-beta.25` to `2.4.0` our Python/PyTest automation scripts are no longer working in a certain scenario. When trying to find an element by Accessibility ID and that element does not exist. Our scripts get hung up on the `element = driver.find_element(By.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, node)` command. It does not hit the `except`. So if the element does exist and is found our scripts work fine, but when it is not found our scripts hang with no error.

```
def find_element(node):
    """
    Looks for a given element and takes a screenshot of the app state.
    """
    element = None
    try:
        element = driver.find_element(By.ACCESSIBILITY_ID, node)
    except (NoSuchElementException):
        return False

    take_screenshot(node)

    return element
```

We do get this in the appium driver logs

```
[debug] [WD Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":"Node was not in the scene tree or found under a different context.","status":7,"sessionId":"redacted"}
```

It would return `False` and we have helper functions that perform logic to help handle navigation and animations of the app.